# Issue using Grunt with grunt-contrib-concat with node require and module.exports

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, concatenation, grunt-contrib-concat

After successfully running grunt concat to concatnate all my node js files into a single file, I get an error when running the file using "$node bundle.js", saying that it cannot find module "./config.js"

In original file: 
var config = require('./config.js');
// do something with config.

In bundle file, it pastes config.js's contents into the bundle file, and then does "var config = require('./config.js);

But obviously this isn't going to be in the same location... isn't concat supposed to put all modules into the same file?

Am I using concat with grunt wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be concatenating Node files! This is not how node (and `require()`) works. We only concatenate JavaScript files intended for the browser in order to minimize page load time by reducing the number of HTTP requests.

So the answer is: **do not concatenate Node JS files!**